# Points of a finite set wihtin a ball

Tags: ds.data-structures, computational-geometry, metric-spaces

I am looking for data-structures to store efficiently a set of points $E$ in an euclidean space of dimension $d$.
In particular, I would like to be able to solve the problem of finding all the point within a ball of center p and radius n without exploring all the points of $E$.

- First remark that it depends of the choice of the distance: it is much more easier for the [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) since a simple b-tree over each coordinates would be sufficient.
- Also remark that I would be happy if finding those points is FPT with the $d$ (dimension) as a parameter.

I guess it is *well-known-well-studied* problem, but I didn't find anything after a (rather short) bibliographical search?

Best,

Comment: When you say FPT, is f(d)polylog(|E|) ok? (I do not know of such a data structure)

Comment: Have you looked into the ‘nearest neighbor search’ literature?

Comment: This sounds like near neighbor search, indeed. The exact problem can be solved in space $n^{O(d)}$ and query time $d^{O(1)} \log n$ per output point. Achieving subexponential space and sublinear query time is known to be hard assuming some complexity conjectures. If you allow approximations then you can do a lot better. Check this recent survey for references https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09823.pdf